# Mysql error code 1222 with a single column selected?

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1222

Can someone explain why I get an error Code 1222 (The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns) after I run this query?

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO table1(id1)
SELECT id2 FROM table2;
```

It's pretty obvious that number of columns are the same, so real issue must be somewhere else. But where? Fields are the exact same:

```
`id2` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'blabla'
```

Only difference is the DB engine (MyISAM on table2, InnoDB on table1), but it can't be linked, because it works like a charm if I add more columns in my INSERT/SELECT without this one.

Any ideas? Thx.

Comment: Can you post a completely reproduce sample, including some data?

Comment: It's complicated because this table has 50K rows and something like 20 cols. IDs are integers from 1 to 10457. Above query works if I create 2 test tables having this data and the same field settings... which does not make any sense, because the exact same parameters (I exported them actually!) are producing an error on the real tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I finally found what was going wrong: a trigger. Basically the number of variables I had at some point did not match the number of columns. (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/stored-program-variables.html).

It seems pretty obvious now that I found the cause, but honestly, MySQL could be more explicit. It's not like I have a single and/or simple query triggered behind the scene (this one was especially a bit complex actually).

For the record error occurred on this field, because that's the one I had forgotten to declare.

Thx for your time guys.

Answer (score 0):

As Tim mentioned, please provide us with table scheme and more information, because I don't see an error in the above.
For example:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO test_cachetags (tag, invalidations) SELECT tag, invalidations FROM cachetags;
```

This query works, where TAG is varchar(255) and invalidations is integer.

Comment: Thing is it works if I create 2 test tables (using the exact same col settings)  filled with this data. But the query on real tables produces this 1222 error. Also, if I remove/add fields to mismatch column count on purpose I get an error Code 1136 (Column count doesn't match value count at row 1). It has something to do with the select (like if i was using UNION not joining the correct number of cols), but what?